# Python network programming project?

Tags: python, networking, project

I was wondering if you guys know any websites or have any ideas on beginner-intermediate level Python network programming projects/practice problems to practice Python network programming? I just finished reading "Foundations of Python Network Programming" and am looking for practice assignments that aren't too difficult to hone my skills.. I've made a simple localhost client/server that lets you add/subtract/multiply/divide numbers.. the "client" passes in 2 numbers and an operation to the server, the server does the calculation and returns the value. Any ideas on what I can do that would be good practice for network programming that doesn't involve installing libraries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My first Python networking project was to write a GUI chat client for the NFC Chat server https://sourceforge.net/projects/nfcchat/.  This was 5-6 years ago - so I'm not sure how much the project has changed.... But the command set was very IRC-ish.  It's not even necessary to dive into the Java codebase to figure it out.  I figured out most of the protocol by telneting to the chat server's port and issuing help commands.  You could also use Wireshark to snoop traffic with their canonical client.

If I remember correctly, I ended up using the following for the project:

- sockets, of course
- asynchat & asyncore
- threading
- wxPython - non-standard library - you could use TkInter instead
- py2exe - non-standard library

Edit:  Or you can try XMPP: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3920.txt

Answer (score 0):

My first net project was a web spider that traversed the web (Obviously), and created a DB to be used as a search engine.

Spider & web search engine in Python (I used mod_python for the web page, but I'd recommend `Django`), and the DB in MySQL.

Create a GUI for managing the DB or Spider (Or both, up to you).

Ended up using:

- Sockets
- DB interactions
- wxPython
- Threading